# HTML Header fixed using jquery floatthead.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use jQuery floatThead plugin. Looks like something is missing. I read through the tutorial. Can anyone help me with it.I am attaching a JSFiddle. Help Appreciated.

```
<div class="wrapper">

<table class="table demo1 table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead> <tr> <th><a href="#" id='demoHeader1'>Header 1</a></th>
        <th><a href="#" id='demoHeader2'>Header 2</a></th> <th><a href="#" id='demoHeader3'>Header...3</a></th> </tr> </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr> <td>Cell Content 1</td> <td>Cell Content 2</td> <td>Cell Content 3</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>More Cell Content 1</td> <td>More Cell Content 2</td> <td>More Cell Content 3</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td> <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td> <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>And Repeat 1</td> <td>And Repeat 2</td> <td>And Repeat 3</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Cell Content 1</td> <td>Cell Content 2</td> <td>Cell Content 3</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>More Cell Content 1</td> <td>More Cell Content 2</td> <td>More Cell Content 3</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td> <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td> <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>And Repeat 1</td> <td>And Repeat 2</td> <td>And Repeat 3</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Cell Content 1</td> <td>Cell Content 2</td> <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr> <tr> <td>More Cell Content 1</td> <td>More Cell Content 2</td> <td>More Cell Content 3</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td> <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td> <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td> </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/otyy8svy/

Comment: What is the expected behaviour ? Are you getting any error messages ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem is that you haven't added the plugin code into your demo. This way you have a console error `$demo1.floatThead is not a function`.

Maybe they have removed their code hosted on cloudflare. So, maybe this is your problem.
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/floatthead/1.2.11/jquery.floatThead.js

## The solution

I've added the code from [plugin's official website](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/dist/jquery.floatThead.js) into the fiddle js box and the thing worked.

https://jsfiddle.net/psy8Lzpk/

So, [get the code](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/dist/jquery.floatThead.js), and include into a `floatThead.js` file hosted into your own server, link it to the page above your main js file and be happy.